# «Не удивительно» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, наречия

> Без него, однако, горизонт очистился и стали видны идиотские тенденции у радикалов обеих партий. Это их не уравнивает, но делает беспомощными и уязвимыми. ***Не удивительно**, что мы вместе с половиной Америки готовы обменять две партии на третью, которая бы помогла стране вернуться к центру самой себя*.
> [А. Генис. "Новая газета"](https://novayagazeta.ru/articles/2021/06/10/tretego-ne-dano)

Собственно, мой вопрос таков: не закралась ли ошибка в самое начало данной фразы — в "не удивительно"? Разве здесь требуется раздельное написание?

Comment: В сам**о**м или в с**а**мом? Кроется где-то — ну не знаю...

Comment: В сАмом начале.

Comment: А Вы считаете, что можно так сказать: кроется **где-то**?

Comment: Я могу исправить на "закралась", если это имеет большое значение. "Скрывается". Мне просто интересен ответ.

Comment: Да, так будет лучше: *не закралась ли ошибка в самое начало фразы?* По сути я согласен с Вами, что слитное написание предпочтительнее, но не могу уверенно сказать, совсем ли не годится раздельное.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Могу я спросить: в моем "кроется" Вас смутила некоторое просторечие или Вы считаете, что оборот был неверно употреблен в данном контексте?

Comment: Нет, "кроется" хорошее слово, только мне кажется, что обычно про ошибку говорят не *кроется где-то,* а *кроется в чём-то.*

Comment: Артем, а мне кажется, что все нормально. _Не кроется ли ошибка в самом начале?_  Кроется (_в чём?_) в начале = таится (_в чём?_) в начале. [http://www.endic.ru/kuzhecov/Krtsja-62690.html] Наказуемая потерей балла **ошибка кроется в последнем предложении**: слово «представить» легко заменить словом «показать», а словосочетание «обязан предоставить» имеет другой смысл: «предоставить некоторую возможность, льготу, услугу». [Ирина Прусс. Сделайте мне красивше // «Знание-сила», 2013]

Comment: Здравствуйте, Римма! Может, вы и правы, но мне кажется, что если "в сАмом начале", то вопрос "где?", а если "в самОм начале", то "в чём?". Я неправ?

Comment: Вечер добрый, Артём! Ольга задает интересные вопросы, не правда ли?

Comment: Ага) Я уже проголосовал за него, теперь ваша очередь))

Comment: Благодарю за лестную оценку!

Comment: Спасибо за принятие моего ответа. Я долго думал, каким словом без не- можно заменить «неудивительно» и пришёл к мысли, что «неудивительно» можно заменить на «закономерно». Я дополнил свой ответ, если есть желание, прочитайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> …пишется слитно, если предложение несет утверждение, и пишется
> раздельно, если несет отрицание.
>
> > Это неудивительно. (Утверждается отсутствие удивления)
> >
> > Это не удивительно. (Отрицается наличие удивления)
>
> [[gramatik.ru](http://gramatik.ru/neudivitelno-ili-ne-udivitelno-slitno-ili-razdelno/#:%7E:text=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%3F-,%C2%AB%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%C2%BB%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%C2%AB%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%C2%BB%3A%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE,%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE.)]

Пишется слитно, потому что утверждается отсутствие удивления.

Кроме того:

> **НЕУДИВИ́ТЕЛЬНО**, в знач. сказ. Не вызывает удивления. *Неудивительно,
> что черты пушкинской, лермонтовской, гоголевской творческой силы
> доселе входят в нашу плоть и кровь.* И. Гончаров, Лучше поздно, чем
> никогда.
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

Обратите внимание на похожее предложение в примере:

*Неудивительно, что черты пушкинской, лермонтовской, гоголевской творческой силы доселе входят в нашу плоть и кровь.*

---

**Дополнение:**

«Неудивительно» тут можно заменить на «закономерно».

У «закономерный» есть оттенок значения:

> **ЗАКОНОМЕ́РНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -рен, -рна, -рно.
>  …
>  Логически обоснованный, оправданный.
> *Никаких качественных изменений в природе
> нет. Такой взгляд на природу был **закономерен**, исторически
> обусловлен. Объяснялся он прежде всего уровнем развития науки о
> природе.* Мезенцев, Энциклопедия чудес.
>
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

*«Неудивительно, что мы…»* т. е. *«Закономерно, что мы…»* — имеется в виду, что это логически обосновано, тут нечему удивляться.

Answer (score 2):

***Не удивительно,** что мы вместе с половиной Америки готовы обменять две партии на третью, которая бы помогла стране вернуться к центру самой себя.*

Нет тут ошибки, так что не будем править автора.  **Стандартная задача с готовым решением!** Так зачем же ее решать самим? Просто почитаем правило Розенталя:http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81

5. Слова категории состояния на -о (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей не слитно **при утверждении:** нетрудно видеть и раздельно **при отрицании**: не трудно видеть (смысл обычно устанавливается **самим пишущим**). Например:

**утверждение:** Неважно, что он о нас думает; Неверно считать создавшееся положение столь трудным; Невозможно выполнить такую сложную работу в короткий срок; Невыгодно уезжать немедленно; Неизвестно, как он будет вести себя дальше; Немудрено, что она отказалась от неинтересной работы; Непозволительно так относиться к старшим; Непонятно, почему они так долго отсутствуют; Неприятно гулять в сырую погоду; Непростительно обманывать чужое доверие; Сегодня на море неспокойно; Неудивительно, что постоянные занятия спортом укрепили его здоровье; Нехорошо оставлять друзей в беде;

**отрицание:** — И это всё? — Не богато; Не весело думать, что праздник уже кончился; Не видно, чтобы больной поправлялся; Не должно упорствовать в ошибочном мнении; Не логично полагать, что события будут повторяться; Не обязательно, чтобы ответ был дан немедленно; Не опасно, что в лечении сделан небольшой перерыв; Не просто провести полную реконструкцию крупного предприятия; Не скромно переоценивать свои заслуги; Не сладко жить в одиночестве; Не случайно, что за помощью он обратился именно к вам; Не странно, что победа досталась сильнейшим; Не существенно для нас, где провести отпуск; Не худо было бы съездить на юг.

**Примечание.**

1. И все это было сказано и известно еще 50 лет назад. Решать самим уже давно решенную задачу – это все равно что пробираться лесом, когда рядом скоростное шоссе. А результат как в истории: **куда ты завел нас, не видно ни зги!**
2. Варианты различаются **интонационно** – при отрицании мы логически подчеркиваем наречие с частицей НЕ. По большому счету именно в этом и состоит **выбор автора**. Ведь **семантика** двух форм практически одна и та же, сколько бы мы ни рассуждали на эту тему в поисках отличия.
3. И еще несколько слов **о замене слова с приставкой НЕ синонимом без НЕ**.

Многие считают, что это **принципиально важный вопрос** и тратят на поиски синонима много сил и времени. А зачем мы это вообще-то делаем, почему  такая замена **считается проверкой?**

При замене слова с НЕ синонимом без НЕ делается проверка  **утвердительного характера предложения**, при этом существование  самого синонима **не является принципиальным**, его можно заменить описательным оборотом, например: Опыт закончился неудачно (имел отрицательный результат).

Тут важно то, что в отрицательной конструкции (противопоставление, усиление отрицания) такую замену **нельзя  сделать**. Также проверяется интонационная модель (но это дополнительная информация).